# Covert list to Map with list in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

This might be a common question, but I did not find anything specific to what I am looking for. Also, I am newbie to Kotlin.

Here is my existing code that I want to simplify in Kotlin. The below code is in Java and I am looking for Kotlin equivalent of it

Travserse through the list of items, identify if it contains MEAT or EGG and accordingly put it in a Map with a LIST. The key to MAP is MEAT/VEG.

```
final Map<TYPE, List<String>> itemtypeToContent = new HashMap<>();
        itemtypeToContent.put(TYPE.MEAT, new ArrayList<>());
        itemtypeToContent.put(TYPE.VEG, new ArrayList<>());

        foodList.forEach(item -> {
            if (containsMeat(item)) {
                itemtypeToContent.get(TYPE.MEAT).add(item);
            } else if (containsEgg(item)) {
                itemtypeToContent.get(TYPE.VEG).add(item);
            } else {
                // log invalid item - skip
            }
        });
        return itemtypeToContent;



enum TYPE {
MEAT,
VEG
}

class Item {
String name,
List<String> ingredients
}
```

input:

```
List<Item> foodList = {{Omlette, {egg, onion, salt, pepper, mushroom}},
                       {ScrambledEggs, {egg, milk, salt, pepper}},
                       {ChickenTacos, {chicken, onion, salt}}
                       {Fries, {potatoes, salt}}}
```

output:

```
Map {MEAT, [{ChickenTacos, {chicken, onion, salt}}]
     VEG,  [{Omlette, {egg, onion, salt, pepper, mushroom}},
            {ScrambledEggs, {egg, milk, salt, pepper}}]}
```

We skipped FRIES because it did not contain meat or egg

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is your question or problem?

Comment: I was wondering if we can simplify this in Kotlin by using groupBy?

Comment: You should also invest some time into explaining your code and what you are doing there, instead of just dumping some code.

Comment: I assumed the input and output would be enough to explain what the code is expected to behave. My bad. Updated the description

Comment: What have you tried in Kotlin?

Comment: I tried associateBy/groupBy with keySelector but felt it was making the code more complicated

Comment: Well, essentially, if people do not immediately understand your question (and the code) after the first read, you will be getting a downvote for "unclear". So it is in your own interest to always go the extra mile when it comes to making it crystal clear and providing all the necessary context possible. SO is a place for high quality questions only (and answers).

Comment: Maybe you should try showing the code you attempted and explaining what you didn't like. That would be more helpful than "rewrite this code in a diff language for me"

Comment: @meso What should the result be when a dish contains both meat and egg?

Comment: Great question - I would prefer it be part of MEAT since that is the first check.

Note - this is not my actual problem, I have tried to simplify this for SO and avoid giving out internal details of my actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to categorise dishes based on whether they contain meat or not, so assuming you only have 2 categories you can do it like this

```
fun main() {
    val dishes = listOf(
        Dish("Omelette", listOf("egg", "onion", "salt", "pepper", "mushroom")),
        Dish("ChickenTacos", listOf("chicken", "onion", "salt")),
        Dish("ScrambledEggs", listOf("egg", "milk", "salt", "pepper")),
        Dish("Fries", listOf("potatoes", "salt"))
    )

    val grouped = dishes.groupBy {
        when {
            containsMeat(it) -> IngredientType.MEAT
            containsVeg(it) -> IngredientType.VEG
            else -> null
        }
    }
        .filterKeys { it != null }


    println(grouped)
}
```

This prints:

```
{
    VEG=[Dish(name=Omelette, ingredients=[egg, onion, salt, pepper, mushroom]), Dish(name=ScrambledEggs, ingredients=[egg, milk, salt, pepper])],
    MEAT=[Dish(name=ChickenTacos, ingredients=[chicken, onion, salt])]
}
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I want, but in this case FRIES would be added as VEG when I want it to be discarded since it does not contain MEAT or EGG

Comment: not sure exactly what the logic for excluding "fries" is, but if you know how you want to group things, you can do it similarly to this

Comment: yes this helps a lot. I can definately try to build things on top of it

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Appreciate it :)